# Qt5.1-android: Qt version for mips missing in QtCreator

Tags: android, qt, build, qt-creator, qt5

I installed `Qt-5.1.0-rc1-android` on linux and added all of the available Qt versions in the `Build & Run` tab in QtCreator (that are `android_armv7`, `android_x86` and `gcc_64`).

But the Creator keeps telling me `Qt version for architecture mips is missing, to add the Qt version, select Options > Build & Run > Qt Versions.`.

Is there some dependency missing I don't know about?

Answer (score 1):

Prefer setup android NDK in Android settings category, after that required Kits will be added automatically. But I'm not sure that Qt 5.1.0 for android contains mips images too. If it doesn't, you should build Qt for mips manually.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! What do you mean by "setup android NDK in Android settings category"? There is no NDK setup, except the path to the NDK. It seems strange that I have to build it manually - it seems to just work for a lot of people (or they just never mentioned that they built parts themselves...).

Comment: So enter path to the NDK and apply settings.

Answer (score 1):

Because of missing support for MIPS in the JavaScript engine used in QtQuick 2, there is no binary package for that architecture.

If your app does not require Qt Quick 2, you can build Qt manually for MIPS. If you require Qt Quick 2 for MIPS, unfortunately the only solution right now is to build from the dev repository (which is under active development and not as stable) or wait for Qt 5.2, where this problem should be fixed.

If your app does not require MIPS support, you can safely ignore the warning in Qt Creator.